# resultset is not matching when executing cypher in neo4j-jdbc

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-java-api

I want to execute cypher statment using neo4j-jdbc jar remotely.

When I execute the below cypher, I am getting resultset with 25 rows in neo4j web console.

```
 MATCH (n:USER) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

When I execute the same program using the neo4j-jdbc remotely, I am getting 0 results.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Neo4jConnection connect = (Neo4jConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474","neo4j","Neo4J");
     final PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("MATCH (n:USER) RETURN n LIMIT 25");
     final ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

     System.out.println(result.getFetchSize());
     result.close();
     statement.close();
     connect.close();
}
```

It is printing size as zero.

I am not sure, what is the mistake exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ResultSet.getFetchSize` returns the number of rows returned from the query. I believe it instead relates to the number of rows that should be returned in each roundtrip to the database.

To check for results from the query try to iterate through `result` and print each row:

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
while (result.next()) { 
    System.out.println(result.getString("n"));
}
```